# CreateFileMapping() fails for Volume

Tags: c, windows, winapi, mapping

I'm having problem with mapping part of volume to memory. Volume is opened successfully, I can read from it, but `CreateFileMapping()` fails. `GetLastError()` returns 87, which has [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) meaning: "The parameter is incorrect." I've created image of the volume and it is handled correctly. This is how I open file and create mapping:

```
/* open function */
fd->handle = CreateFile(name, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
/* mapping function */
LARGE_INTEGER li;
li.QuadPart = offset;
handle = CreateFileMapping(fd->handle, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, li.u.HighPart, li.u.LowPart, NULL);
```

I'm working on Windows XP SP3 (but code should also work on newer versions), administrator account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CreateFileMapping only supports mapping files.  It's returning the "The parameter is incorrect" because the handle isn't for a file.